# Using Netbeans Swing UI Builder with an eclipse project

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-6.9

I have an eclipse based Swing project and want to import that in Netbeans. the latest version 6.9 of netbeans does provide import of eclipse project, however the GUI builder does not act on the java files .Thus, we can't do a preview for the Swing UI for the imported project.
Is there a work around for this ?

thanks in advance
dhawanmayur.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans GUI builder uses an intermediate xml file to generate java source (a file with ".form" extension. It cannot reverse engeener hand written java gui code.

Use WindowBuilder instead

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/windowbuilder-pro-gui-designer